# How can I bend wire that is too thick to manage easily?

Tags: electrical, wiring, pool, pump

Such a silly question but please help me! The wires leading to my pool pump are probably 10 or 12 gauge.  When i bend them in a loop i cant get them around the screw because there is no give to the wire.  Can i remove the screw, place the loop over the hole and re-screw?
What if the screw doesnt come out completely?

I want a secure connection and really want to loop around the screw.

How do the pros get this done?

Comment: What are you trying to attach the wire to? Is the device you're connecting to rated for this size wire?

Comment: It is. Its a 220 pool pump.

Comment: You're trying to attach the wires to the motor, or to a receptacle that the motor can plug into?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that it's #10, but even #12 can seem like a pretty thick wire when you're, even casually, used to #14.

I'm surprised your pump receptacle doesn't have clamps instead of screws. Is it a 20 amp, twist lock, single receptacle?

Without using force make sure the device screws are completely backed out, but don't remove them. Strip off about 1” of insulation to get a good size hook. As you're bending it, stop short of a full hook to more of a “U” shape. Put the wire under the screw and complete the hook with needle nose or diagonal pliers, the end of wire strippers whatever works before tightening the screw. Subtle bends and angles can make all the difference getting the wire under the screw.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could take the screw out (if it comes out). Just make sure you have good contact, as (10 or 12 guage is a reasonably heavy cable, I believe).

> How do the pros get this done?

Crimp connectors... Crimp the connector onto the end of the wire(s) and secure the prongs or ring on the connector under the screw.

(Examples of crimp connectors here: [Crimp connectors photo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aKabelschuh_verschiedene_commons.jpg) larger ones are available, though tend to be uninsulated.)